# Can't access selenium grid console. HTTP ERROR: 403 Forbidden for Proxy

Tags: ant, installation, command-prompt, http-status-code-403, selenium-grid

I've downloaded `Selenium Grid`, I believe I have it configured all correctly as I ran a successful "sanity check", which checks your configuration.

I have ant configured correctly as well.

I then tried to launch the hub via the `cmd` prompt by typing "ant launch-hub."

It appeared to work fine in the terminal.

I then tried to check to see if it was running, I've opened my browser and pointed it to localhost:4444/console as was written in the tutorial, but then I got the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 403

Forbidden for Proxy
RequestURI=/console
```

Don't know what to do next, any ideas?

Comment: Also, the next step of the tutorial is to launch the remote control, and when I type the command for this (ant launch-remote-control) the build fails. In case that detail helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had something already running on that port, so I just changed to a different port. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you downloaded the older version of selenium grid. Its better you use the latest version of Grid (Grid 2.0) as the older version is no longer supported. Newer version doesnt require ant to launch it. Latest version of grid can be downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) . You must download the standalone version. To get started on Grid 2.0, refer this [wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2)